# Android Studio - How can i get the Gradle tab on my Android studio side bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, dart

Can someone help me with how can i get the Gradle tab on the side dock.

I have been wanting to get my app signed and i cannot seem to find the gradle bar anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**To show Gradle on sidebar of your Android Studio, Follow below steps::**

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click On View Menu From Toolbar -> Tool Windows -> Gradle

This steps will open your Gradle to sidebar of Android studio.
[image]

Comment: mine does not have the gradle option.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of available tools you have in your android studio

Comment: Somehow i managed to get it. Went to search for gradle at the search bar and clicked on "trust this project" when the dialog opened.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio,

Go To Help -> Find Action -> type "Gradle" press enter

##### OR

Go To Help -> Find Action -> type "Gradle" select Link Gradle option

either option will show you gradle tab.

[image]